# Dot product between two 3D tensors

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensordot

I have two 3D tensors, tensor `A` which has shape `[B,N,S]` and tensor `B` which also has shape `[B,N,S]`. What I want to get is a third tensor `C`, which I expect to have `[B,B,N]` shape, where the element `C[i,j,k] = np.dot(A[i,k,:], B[j,k,:]`. I also want to achieve this is a vectorized way.

Some further info: The two tensors `A` and `B` have shape `[Batch_size, Num_vectors, Vector_size]`. The tensor `C`, is supposed to represent the dot product between each element in the batch from `A` and each element in the batch from `B`, between all of the different vectors.

Hope that it is clear enough and looking forward to you answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [331]: A=np.random.rand(100,200,300)                                                              
In [332]: B=A
```

The suggested `einsum`, working directly from the

```
C[i,j,k] = np.dot(A[i,k,:], B[j,k,:]
```

expression:

```
In [333]: np.einsum( 'ikm, jkm-> ijk', A, B).shape                                                   
Out[333]: (100, 100, 200)
In [334]: timeit np.einsum( 'ikm, jkm-> ijk', A, B).shape                                            
800 ms ± 25.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`matmul` does a `dot` on the last 2 dimensions, and treats the leading one(s) as batch.  In your case 'k' is the batch dimension, and 'm' is the one that should obey the `last A and 2nd to the last of B` rule.  So rewriting the `ikm,jkm...` to fit, and transposing `A` and `B` accordingly:

```
In [335]: np.einsum('kim,kmj->kij', A.transpose(1,0,2), B.transpose(1,2,0)).shape                     
Out[335]: (200, 100, 100)
In [336]: timeit np.einsum('kim,kmj->kij',A.transpose(1,0,2), B.transpose(1,2,0)).shape              
774 ms ± 22.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Not much difference in performance.  But now use `matmul`:

```
In [337]: (A.transpose(1,0,2)@B.transpose(1,2,0)).transpose(1,2,0).shape                             
Out[337]: (100, 100, 200)
In [338]: timeit (A.transpose(1,0,2)@B.transpose(1,2,0)).transpose(1,2,0).shape                      
64.4 ms ± 1.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

and verify that values match (though more often than not, if shapes match, values do to).

```
In [339]: np.allclose((A.transpose(1,0,2)@B.transpose(1,2,0)).transpose(1,2,0),np.einsum( 'ikm, jkm->
     ...:  ijk', A, B))                                                                              
Out[339]: True
```

I won't try to measure memory usage, but the time improvement suggests it too is better.

In some cases `einsum` is optimized to use `matmul`.  Here that doesn't seem to be the case, though we could play with its parameters.  I'm a little surprised the `matmul` is doing so much better.

===

I vaguely recall another SO about `matmul` taking a short cut when the two arrays are the same thing, `A@A`.  I used `B=A` in these tests.

```
In [350]: timeit (A.transpose(1,0,2)@B.transpose(1,2,0)).transpose(1,2,0).shape                      
60.6 ms ± 1.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [352]: B2=np.random.rand(100,200,300)                                                             
In [353]: timeit (A.transpose(1,0,2)@B2.transpose(1,2,0)).transpose(1,2,0).shape                     
97.4 ms ± 164 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

But that only made a modest difference.

```
In [356]: np.__version__                                                                             
Out[356]: '1.16.4'
```

My BLAS etc is standard Linux, nothing special.

Comment: Nice answer. I get similar timings with `einsum` and `@` (np ver 1.15.3). Is your improvement because you are using np>1.16.0?

Comment: I updated `numpy` and now I get similar timings. Probably because of [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#matmul-is-now-a-ufunc)

Comment: I mean similar timings to the ones in the answer

Comment: My numpy is 1.16.4.  I also used `B=A`, and matmul takes a modest shortcut in the `A@A` case, but that doesn't account for most of the time difference.

Comment: Yes, I got timings like the one in your answer, after updating numpy

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) such as:

```
np.einsum( 'ikm, jkm-> ijk', A, B)
```

with the subscripts `'ikm, jkm-> ijk'`, you can specify which dimension are reduced with the Einstein convention. The third dimension of both arrays A and B here named `'m'` will be reduced as the `dot` operation does on vectors.

Comment: Thanks! Can you translate that in matrix multiplication ops?

Comment: @gorjan not sure sure I understand what you want me to do?

Comment: Instead of going with something like `einsum` I am wondering whether your solution can be written as one/several matrix multiplications (I assume it can). From what I know, `einsum` is just syntactic sugar that wraps one or more invocations of `matmul`.

Comment: @gorjan I see and maybe there is an easy solution, but unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to find a way that will not do extra calculation, that would end up to do like in the solution with `tensordot` of *Learning is a mess*

Comment: Transpose the arrays so `kim,kmj->kij`, then use `@`

Comment: Hey @hpaulj, can you post an answer as well? Even though the accepted answer works just fine, it creates a huge tensor under the hood to perform the tensor reduction which makes it unfeasible to use it in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
C = np.diagonal( np.tensordot(A,B, axes=(2,2)), axis1=1, axis2=3)
```

from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html#numpy.tensordot

Explanation

The solution is a composition of two operations. First the tensor product between A and B over their third axis as you want it. This outputs a rank-4 tensor, that you want to reduce to a rank-3 tensor by taking equal indices on axis 1 and 3 (your `k` in your notation, note that `tensordot` gives a different axis order than your maths). This can be done by taking the diagonal, as you can do when reducing a matrix to the vector of its diagonal entries.

Comment: Please try again, first version had wrong axis indices.

Comment: It would be useful if you can explain a bit. One liners are not much help, even if it works.

Comment: This method, as it is now, is very inefficient compared to the above `einsum`. You are creating an array `N` times larger than `C` and then taking the diagonal. It is at least 10x slower than `einsum` for small arrays and potentially orders of magnitude slower for large arrays.

Comment: @Brenlla Correct I just benchmarked them and mine is 10x slower, plus larger temporary memory footprint I guess. I do not understand the downvote though..